# Funnel dynamic RegEx

Tags: regex, google-analytics, goal-tracking

I'm adding in a funnel for a specific journey to upload a photo via Facebook vs non Facebook vs YouTube etc. An example URL is below:

http://picturewall.mariecurie.org.uk/Upload/Step23/3631432911935?accessToken=CAAKeGTXwMDABAG7LSgs7YR7PTJ6ORSp2OhXUla85jr10UCOMNY9cTI2qVO8GaufA4p48bOYVcSexd0u50spJdOCYJXEUWZAhLZCu9ZAw52qU8Qyy3ZCO0MGotO0JXrkcDkZBzj5XE5ZA705KocaPQzCNR86ZBUDilzabfF37G7TC2usLFHT7uNJYgZBMc5DB9USPJi2OSdHHXGJz8W1nJfnq&PostType=Facebook – choose FB photo

What I want to do is to ensure that this step (choose Facebook photo) is tracked by picking up Step23 and PostType=Facebook as Step23 is used for other journeys where PostType=YouTube as an example.

I've suggested the below may work (with the view already filtered to just picturewall visitors): 
/Upload/Step23(.*?)(?!PostType=Facebook)

Is that the correct approach?

Comment: Welcome in StackOverflow. Please edit your post. Correct your link to hide this very long address. Also remove all unimportant sentences from this post (introducing yourself, thanking for help etc). Such sentences are called 'noise'. Without it question is easier to analyze. If you want to respond me add comment starting with @rtruszk

Comment: As I've learned recently, lookaheads don't work for Google regex. So you could try something like this: ^/Upload/Step23/(.*)&PostType=Facebook&

Comment: @rtruszk -appreciate the feedback.

Comment: @nyuen - not all the URLs have a / after Step - e.g. some say step2? - I wonder if just putting ^/Upload/Step2(.*)&PostType=Facebook& would still work or would ^/Upload/Step2\?(.*)&PostType=Facebook& be better?

Comment: The first one seems better.

Comment: @nyuen - thanks for the feedback. Doesn't seem to work still. Will try a few other variations! Thanks for your help!

Comment: By the way, I thought you had a typo at first, but your Step2 is actually Step23 which would make a different to regex.

Comment: @nyuen - there are multiple versions of which we have a Step2 and Step23. Step23 has / after it but Step2 has ? after it.